# A pointer that does not print the first three words in a sentence

Tags: c

Dont have any code get and i am stuck on how to solve this problem.
I want the code to let the user input a long sentence and then a pointer that doesnt print the first 3 words of any given sentence. The tricky part for me is that the char is not defined at start so I cant just remove the words I wish.

Exampel:

Hello I neeed help with this code

help with this code

Comment: So what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Nothing get using paper and pen to try to come up with a solution, One of them are to seperate them into a list and then only print 3 to max array.                                      0 hello 1 i 2 neeed 3 help 4 with 5 this 6 code and then tell the pointer to print 3 to 6 dont know if this would work. the other one is that it goes of spaces between the words and only prints after 4 spaces

Comment: if anyone has a link to how I could solve the problem just to get me started don't want any specific code

Comment: Sorry, but SO is for specific problems with solutions that are useful to others. The help you ask for is help you should get from your teacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go along the line and count the number of spaces

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 256

int main(void) {
    // Reading user input
    char buf[INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    fgets(buf, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);

    int words_to_skip = 3;
    char* current_pos = &buf[0];

    for (; words_to_skip > 0 && *current_pos != 0; current_pos++) {
        // If current char is space - then we reached the next word
        if (*current_pos == ' ') {
            words_to_skip--;
        }
    }

    if (*current_pos == 0) {
        printf("Not enough words entered\n");
    } else {
        printf("%s", current_pos);
    }
}
```

Or, using built-in `strchr()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 256

int main(void) {
    // Reading user input
    char buf[INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    fgets(buf, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);

    int words_to_skip = 3;
    char* current_pos = &buf[0];

    while (current_pos != 0 && *current_pos != 0 && words_to_skip > 0) {
        current_pos = strchr(current_pos, ' ');
        if(current_pos != 0) {
            current_pos++;
        }
        words_to_skip--;
    }
    if (current_pos == 0) {
        printf("Not enough words entered\n");
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", current_pos);
    }
}
```